# Get vim on a remote server without system administration permissions

Tags: python, vim, server, vi

I have been given a profile (with /home directory) on a remote Linux server to work on projects that need powerful computing resources. I'd like to use Vim to edit code (mostly python) on the remote server as it can be run through a shell and doesn't require a slow GUI exchange. Currently, the Debian distribution on the remote server has a barebones vi installed and no Vim. Is there a way to install a Vim (perhaps in my home directory?) without superuser permissions?

Comment: Why not ask admins to install real `vim`?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to install vim locally, for example downloaded from a binary, or compiled from source with

```
git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
cd vim/src
make
```

From there, you can simply add the directory you compiled it to to PATH.

Comment: Thanks! Will this vim configuration follow the same startup procedure as the built-in vi? i.e. will it run /home/myhomedir/.vimrc?

Comment: I believe so, but worth double checking. If it doesn't work, there are tons of ways to get around this. I think there is a keyword argument when starting vim to choose a specific file as your vimrc, you could alias that to vim.